# How can I convert a model trained in tensorflow 2 to a tensorflow 1 frozen graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2

I would like to train a model using tensorflow 2 but afterwards I need to use a converter that is only compatible with tensorflow 1.  Is it possible and if so how can I convert a model that was trained using tensorflow 2 to a tensorflow 1 format?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow!  Would you be able to provide some example code of a basic TensorFlow 2 model being created, and some system to check if the exported model is compatible with TensorFlow 1?  That might make it easier to figure out how to link the two

Comment: I am using https://github.com/tensorflow/models to fine tune a model from the TF2 model zoo.  

SSD MobileNet v2 320x320 from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md   

To fine tune the model I am using the models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py  

`python object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --alsologtostderr --model_dir=../tf2_model_test/ --pipeline_config_path=~/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/pipeline.config`  

I believe all I will need is the output of the conversion to be usable with TF1.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no method that reliably converts your TF2 model to TF1, you can always save the trained parameters (weights, biases) and used them later to initiate your TF1 graph.
I did it for some other purpose before. You can save as follows:

```
weights = []
for layer in model.layers:

    w = layer.get_weights()
    if len(w)>0:
      print(layer.name)
      weights.append(w)


with open('mnist_weights.pkl', 'wb') as f:
  pickle.dump(weights, f)
```

Where for each layer `w[0]=weights` and `w[1]=biases`